# conditional for orderBy and filter in angularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

```
.roster(ng-repeat="player in team.playerProfiles | orderBy: '-pRating' |filter: team.selected.playerId | limitTo: 1 " )
```

I realized this didn't work. Is there anyway to make a conditional that detects if team.selected.playerId exist and run the filter, then if it does not exist, to do the orderBy instead?

Comment: It would be much easier (and more testable) to just create a filter function and have your filtering logic there

Comment: yeah. Reading up on custom filters. Not sure exactly how it would work. Any pointers in the right direction - much appreciated.